# Multivariable Piecewise continuous function on a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control

In optimal control and differential equations we often deal with piecewise continuous functions. Here I want to extend the piecewise continuous function from an interval
in $\mathbb{R}$ to a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for which I
think there should be a standard definition. But I searched online
for a long time, yet still could not find one.

Recall that a one-variable piecewise continuous function is defined
as:

A real-valued function $u(t)$, $t_{0}\le t\le t_{f}$ , is said to
be piecewise continuous, denoted $u\in\hat{C}[t_{0},t_{f}]$, if there
is a finite (irreducible) partition $t_{0}=\theta_{0}<\theta_{1}<\cdot\cdot\cdot<\theta_{N}<\theta_{N+1}=t_{f}$
such that $u$ may be regarded as a continuous function in $[\theta_{k},\theta_{k+1}]$
for each $k=0,1,...,N$.

So my question is if I can define a multi-variable piecewise continuous
function on a compact set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as follows:

A real-valued function $u(x)$, $x\in E$ is said to be piecewise
continuous if there is a finite partition of $E$ on each coordinate
such that $u$ may be regarded as a continuous function on each polytope.

The source of the question is from the book of Chachuat: Nonlinear
and Dynamic Optimization, in theorem A.55 on page xv of appendix A.5:
"Suppose that $f(t,x,p)$ is piecewise continuous in $(t,x,p)$...",
so $f(t,x,p)$ is multivariate piecewise continuous function but Chachuat
does not give the explicit definition.